# How to find the .cpp File of a node?

Tags: node

I have a node, where i cant find the .cpp file of it. Is there a way to find the exact path of the nodes .cpp file? I have a structure how the program is built up in rqt_graph. And there is a node where i dont know where it is created. Is there a command for rosnodes or something?

Answer (score 1):

The "node" you are mentioning is the executable created by compilling the workspace where the package is located. You should check the `CMakelists.txt` file in order to check which .ccp file correspond to that executable. You should see it at the same level as `package.xml` and src folder inside your package.